# code problems convert string to chart execl

Tags: c++, string, char

I had this error when I compiled my code. The execl are for a file c++ who screen data in a LCD on a raspberry:

```
SerialPort.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
SerialPort.cpp:121:50: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int 
execl(const char*, const char*, ...)’
   execl("/mondossier/programmeYacine", data, data);
```

And this is my main:

```
main()
{
    std::string cmd = "0";
    while(true){
            std::cout << "Entrez Commande" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> cmd;
            SerialPort* comSerie = new SerialPort();
            comSerie->writeSerialPort(cmd);
            sleep(1);
            std::string data = comSerie->readSerialPort();
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
            execl("/mondossier/programmeYacine", data, data);
            delete(comSerie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `execl()` is expecting argument of type `const char*` and you are passing `std::string`.

You can use `std::string.c_str()` function to get respective *C-string* representation. which is of type `onst char*`.

Change the line `execl("/mondossier/programmeYacine", data, data);` to `execl("/mondossier/programmeYacine", data.c_str(), data.c_str());`